# How to evaluate $ \int_0^{2 \pi} \sin((2n-1)x) \ln(\sin(x)+5/4) dx $?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, fourier-series, closed-form, recursion

Is there a closed form for

$$f(2n-1) = \int_0^{2 \pi} \sin((2n-1)x) \ln(\sin(x)+5/4) dx $$

Of course this comes from searching the fourier series of $ \ln(\sin(x)+5/4) dx $.

In fact, it is equivalent to searching for that Fourier series since

$\int_0^{2 \pi} \sin((2n)x) \ln(\sin(x)+5/4) dx = \int_0^{2 \pi} \cos(nx) \ln(\sin(x)+5/4) dx = 0$

I know $f(4n + 1)$ has the opposite sign as $f(4n + 3)$.

Maybe using the fourier series of $\sin(x)^n$ and the taylor series of $\ln(\sin(x)+5/4) $ helps.

Or maybe we can use formulas such as $\cos(nx) = 2 \cos((n-1)x) \cos(x) - \cos((n-2) x) $ and the sine analogue.

Many thanks.

Comment: I suppose you can get a closed form - integrate by part and then go to the complex plane to evaluate $\frac{\cos((2n-1)x)\cos(x)}{\sin(x)+5/4}$ integrating along a circle of radius 1. The roots of denominator lay on this circle, so you have to add additional small circles around these roots to get a closed contour. But it seems the program is feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Without Fourier series.*

Just a bit of patience with integrals to see obvious patterns.
$$I_n=\int_0^{2\pi}\sin [(2 n-1) x]\, \log \left(\sin (x)+\frac{5}{4}\right)\,dx=\color{blue}{(-1)^{n+1}\frac{  4^{1-n}}{2 n-1}\pi}$$

Comment: I accepted because you are correct and you are first.
This is all I personally needed.
I must add that I encourage others to give explainations.
This answer might give a storm of conjectures from me but first I have to really think hard about it :)